# How do I run multiple terminal commands in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I want to run these commands after one another:

```
npm run build
git add build/
git commit -m "Latest version of build"
git push
firebase deploy
```

In Visual Studio Code terminal window. How do I do that? Copy/pasting does work, but maybe I could create a script or something?

I already tried to create a '.bat' file, but only the first command is executed then. '.sh' and '.cmd' also do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty solution is to make everything into one line, by separating
the commands with `&&`:

```
npm run build && git add build/ && git commit -m "Latest version of build" && git push && firebase deploy
```

For more complex solutions see :

- [Run Batch Files (DOS Commands) From Visual Studio](https://www.thoughtco.com/run-batch-files-from-visual-studio-3424204)
- [Quick Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lkytal.quicktask)